# Passing Value from Kendo DDL to ActionLink/ActionImage without submitting values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, actionlink

VS'12 KendoUI InternetApplication Template C# asp.net EF Code First

I got 2 dropdownlist pages 1 page uses the DropDownList For Posting values to a ModelView the other is just returning by ID.

**Qeustion**

Basically i want to stay in the view with a DDL that a user can select from. Left of this DDL there is a Actionlink that should be able to go to a new ACtion with the selected parameter. But my model values are always null. How does one pass this value?

**DropDownList**

```
                <label for="Prospects">Prospect:</label>
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m.Prospects)
                      //.Name("clients")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px"}) //, id = "clients"})
                      .OptionLabel("Select Prospect...")
                      .DataTextField("ProspectName")
                      .DataValueField("ProspectID")
                      .DataSource(source => {
                           source.Read(read => {
                               read.Action("GetCascadeProspects", "AddCCCTRST");
                           });
                      })
                  )
```

**ActionLink**

```
@Html.ActionImage("ADD", "Prospect", new { id=Model.Prospects.FirstOrDefault() } , "~/Images/Navigation/Add.PNG", "Add")

..., new { id=Model.Prospects.FirstOrDefault() } ,...,...) 
// the Model is null here, how can i pass my value to this actionlink / actionimage?
```

(The ActionImage is from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896439/action-image-mvc3-razor)) if the code needs posted here please advise. *(the custom ActionImage is working i just can't pass the value.... )*

> UPDATES *Model*

```
public class ViewModelCCTRST
{
    public string Clients { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dbClient> AvailableClients { get; set; }
    public string Prospects { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dbProspect> AvailableProspects { get; set; }
    public string Countys { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dbCounty> AvailableCounties { get; set; }
    public string TownShips { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dbTownShip> AvailableTownShip { get; set; }
    public string Ranges { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dbRange> AvailableRanges { get; set; }
    public string Sections { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dbSection> AvailableSection { get; set; }
    public string Tracts { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<dbTract> AvailableTracts { get; set; }
}
```

> Controller *A JsonResult GET Method and Post Request

```
    public JsonResult GetCascadeTracts(int sections)
    {
        var tract = db.Tracts.AsQueryable();

        if (0 != sections)
        {
            tract = tract.Where(o => o.SectionID == sections);
        }

        return Json(tract.Select(o => new { TractID = o.TractID, TractName = o.TractNumber }),    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ViewModelCCTRST model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            //string clt = model.Clients;
            string pro = model.Prospects;
            string cnt = model.Countys;
            string twn = model.TownShips;
            string rng = model.Ranges;
            string sct = model.Sections;
            string trt = model.Tracts;

            return Content(cnt + twn + rng + sct + trt);
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("");
        }
    }
```

**As Discussed below i do have values in my `Post` method, but i do not have any values in my `View`(This is where i want to be able to have values to use my `Actionlinks` w/o refreshing the page) also, If I tie the `Model.(w/e the data is)` into the `action links` they give me a `null reference`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add id to Actionlink

   ```
   @Html.ActionLink("Add", "Create", new { controller = "Client"}, new {id="AddClient"})
   ```
2. add  to catch onclick events

   ```
    $('#AddClient').click(function (e) {
       var val = $("#Clients").val();
       var href = "/Client/Create/" + val;
       this.href = ""; //clears out old href for reuse
       this.href = href; //changes href value to currently slected dropdown value
   });
   ```

[srcs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705964/read-control-dropdownlist-from-view-within-the-view)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kendo template` for this. **Reference: [Kendo DropDownList / Customizing templates](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/template.html)**

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("customers")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 400px" })
      .DataTextField("ContactName")
      .DataValueField("CustomerID")
      .DataSource(source =>
      {
          source.Read(read =>
          {
              read.Action("GetCustomers", "Home");
          });
      })
      .Height(300)
      .Template("<img src=\"" + Url.Content("~/Content/web/Customers/") +  "${data.CustomerID}.jpg\" alt=\"${data.CustomerID}\" />" +
                        "<dl>" +
                            "<dt>Contact:</dt><dd>${ data.ContactName }</dd>" +
                            "<dt>Company:</dt><dd>${ data.CompanyName }</dd>" +
                        "</dl>")
)
```

**UPDATE**

You are getting null value because you haven't assign `Name` to your kendo control. Without doing this, the control value will not be bind to your model.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m.Prospects)
                  .Name("Prospects")         // assign appropriate name
                  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px"}) //, id = "clients"})
                  .OptionLabel("Select Prospect...")
                  .DataTextField("ProspectName")
                  .DataValueField("ProspectID")
                  .DataSource(source => {
                       source.Read(read => {
                           read.Action("GetCascadeProspects", "AddCCCTRST");
                       });
                  })
              )
```

Comment: `Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.DropDownListBuilderBase<Kendo.Mvc.UI.DropDownList,Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.DropDownListBuilder>.Template(string)' has some invalid argument` **and** `Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' to 'string' ` when running  2nd sample of your answer.

Comment: I think the error you are facing is because there is no string for template in the argument of `Template`. You have to pass the data as argument for `Add` action method. I don't know what is your logic, but I can tell you, that the error you are facing is `@Url.Action(\"Add\", new { id = Model.Prospects.FirstOrDefault()})` due to this. Refer to the link I have provided for Kendo, it will definitely help you..

Comment: I think we are miscomunicating, I'm strying to figure out why in `@Url.Action(\"Add\", new { id = Model.Prospects.FirstOrDefault()}` this part `new { id = Model.Prospects.FirstOrDefault()` isn't holding a value. This is how i'm accessing the data from my controller after a submit so maybe its not there because no submit? - in that case the qeustion is still there , how to get the selected value from the DDL to my actionlink. Values are `[Null]`

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle: Please share the code for controller ActionMethod. What you are expecting to pass. Also, show the Model class, so that I can get idea about it..

Comment: are you wanting the full controller? ill post just one of the Get and the Post for now let me know if this suffices

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle: i have updated the answer. You need to assign `Name` property properly... See this: [how to pass the ID of the kendo Ui dropdown selected value onto the controller?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12054298/how-to-pass-the-id-of-the-kendo-ui-dropdown-selected-value-onto-the-controller)

Comment: i was under the assumption that when using the `For` Keyword as in `DropDownListFor` the name is handled automatically. - i Will change and test asap!!

Comment: the template your giving me is great if I wanted to have more data in my DropDowns, this is however NOT what i am trying to accomplish. Is there a way for me to use `.Template(@Html.ActionImage("ADD", "Prospect", new { id="editLink_Prospect" } , "~/Images/Navigation/Add.PNG", "Add"))` or somehow get the id from the DDL into the standalone ActionLink?

Comment: After the last update i attempted i was hoping to see change by using `id="${data.ProspectID}" ` in my actionlink, but it returns itself as a string not a Script Function.

Comment: Not wasting points, though i cam up with my own solution i think this was very helpful, therefor you get the bounty , before it expires, thanks for all you attempts and help, ill be using template in the future.