# How to compare dates in 2 columns of a row in Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo UI Grid, in that I have 2 columns StartDate and EndDate. 
While doing inline editing, I want to compare that StartDate should not be greater than EndDate.
I am doing this below in the custom validation of the StartDate Field.
But the var StartDate is getting null value assigned.

```
model: {
                id: "BusinessAreaDivisionMappingId",
                fields: {
                    BusinessAreaDivisionMappingId: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: false },

                    StartDate: {
                        from: "BusinessAreaDivisionMappingEntity.StartDate", type: "date",
                        validation:
                            {
                                required: true,
                                dateComparisonValidation: function (input) {
                                    debugger;
                                    if (input && (input.attr("name") == "StartDate"|| input.attr("name") == "EndDate")) {
                                        input.attr("data-dateComparisonValidation-msg", "Start Date cannot be more than End Date");
                                        var startDate = input.closest(".k-edit-form-container").find("[name='StartDate']").data("kendoDatePicker");
                                        var endDate = input.closest(".k-edit-form-container").find("[name='EndDate']").data("kendoDatePicker");
                                        if (Date(startDate) > Date(endDate)) {
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                    },
                    EndDate: { from: "BusinessAreaDivisionMappingEntity.EndDate", type: "date" }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPDATE*

Here fully working example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/IqeNA

---

I think it's really better for user expirience to not be able to select invalid values compare to see that those values not valid an reselect them.

If you agree with that that add custom editor for your columns with dates:

```
var dateEditor = function (container, options) {
var input = $('<input />');

input.appendTo(container)
  .kendoDatePicker({
    format: "dd.MM.yyyy"
  });
var datePicker = input.data("kendoDatePicker");
  switch (options.field) {
    case "startDate":
      if (options.model.finishDate) {
        datePicker.max(options.model.finishDate);
      }
      break;

    case "finishDate":
      if (options.model.startDate) {
        datePicker.min(options.model.startDate);
      }
      break;
  }
};
```

Read about custom editors here

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.editor

If you have troubles with adding editors for inline editor read that article

[Kendo Grid using inline editing and custom editor dropdown control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952263/kendo-grid-using-inline-editing-and-custom-editor-dropdown-control)

Comment: This is not working, Suppose
Step 1: I select start date 6th Sept.
Step 2: I can select enddate 5thSept.

Comment: What not working? You have errors? That is perfectly working solution i use it in production

Comment: In your case you named model fields starting with capital letters. 'StartDate' vs 'startDate'. Try debug it first, replace names with those which you use in model

Comment: I have already done that. I think Datepicker is taking the previous range from cache and hence I can select the invalid date.
Do you have any idea how to make caching disabled for datepicker in a grid column.?

Comment: there is no caching for datepicker ranges. Post your model code and how you inpliment custom editor

Comment: Better post it to js fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/FGtGy/15/ you can eddit that example

Comment: I have updated in the given jsfiddle link. It wont be showing output because I have not hard coded model data. I have just copy pasted from my source code.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy..! its working. I just have to think now of user not making date changes by directly editing in the text box because as of now it can be changed and StartDate can be made greater than EndDate.